# AngularJS: How to create a one time page?

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering how one would create a one time page in angularjs. As an example, a user enters his details into a form and submits. If the submission is successful, the user is forwarded to a "thank you" which is only accessible once otherwise forward to the home page for instance. Something similar to the traditional flash message.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want to show is a simple "thank you" screen, my advice would be to keep it simple and use a modal splash. It's what I usually do.

Check out this [very good example](http://popdevelop.com/2014/07/sexy-splash-modal-using-bootstrap-css3-and-angularjs/) (and demo [here](http://popdevelop.github.io/angular-splash-demo/)).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Will improve the answer when I leave work. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: + 1 for the suggestion. Played around with it yesterday and will come in very handy in the future, however, this solution does not work in this instance. For instance, how would one create a custom page based on which form was submitted. Also, because of the way the modals work, it doesn't close when you click back button.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [**Toastr**](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) in that case.

[Here](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) you can find more examples.

Comment: I am looking for a custom view, not a toast message

Answer (score 1):

I am new to angular, but I think you can set a $scope variable such as 'allowVisit' and set it to true if you need to allow viewing the thank you page, and If the thank you page found this variable false, it should change the location to /home

Comment: I was originally thinking the same... however, I was hoping for a solution which uses the routing mechanism before it reaches the page, i.e. if flag isn't set, forward to home page